# how to set permissions to full control in c# registry

Tags: c#, forms, regedit

I've a key named "a" located in HKLM\SOFTWARE
It's permission is set to Deny...
I'm trying to set it to a full control like that:

```
     using (RegistryKey rk =
        Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\a"))
                {
                    string gname = Environment.UserDomainName + @"\" + Environment.UserName;
                    RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
                    rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(gname, RegistryRights.ReadKey, AccessControlType.Allow));
                    rk.SetAccessControl(rs);
                }
```

but it throws an exception at

```
    using (RegistryKey rk =
        Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\a"))
```

saying that "Requested registry access is not allowed."
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`RegistryKey.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\a")` does not open the key for writing. Try using the `RegistryKey.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\a", true)` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify that you want the key to be writable.